# How can I use a generated dynamic variable?

Tags: matlab, eval

I made some dynamic variable with eval function in Matlab,Now I need to use these variables, I mean I need to check the value of these variable(for example in a condition-if end-) or do any other operations with these variable!! but I don't know how?!
do you have any idea?

Comment: What about providing an example?

Comment: for example: eval(sprintf('R%d',1))

Comment: From that example, it sounds a lot like you should be using arrays instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable created with `eval` like any other variable:

```
>> eval('a=5')
a =
     5
>> a
a =
     5
```